# PHP PDO fatal error while connecting MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting following fatal error when i use PDO to connect and retrieve some output from MySQL

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /home/ ... line 21

My PHP Code:

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=abc;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'abc','abc');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT current_date()'); //line 21
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You don't read "your" code (copied from somewhere?) so you've got errors.

Comment: yes... i thought "new PDO" has become $pdo :(

Comment: @ElonThan : could you please let me know how to read the row values then ? is it $row[0] ?

Comment: No, I can't. Go and learn PHP before trying to write code in it.

Comment: Thats expected !! but I could not find enough detail on http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT current_date()'); //line 21
```

To:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT current_date()'); //line 21
```

Because `$pdo` is not defined here but `$dbConnection`

Comment: could you please let me know how to read the row values then ? is it $row[0] ?

Answer (score 1):

try changing the 4th line to

```
$stmt= $dbConnection->prepare...
```